# CATALINA_OPTS Debugging Options

Tags: bash, tomcat, catalina

I want to use below code to start the apache-tomcat,

```
#!/bin/bash
DUMPSPATH='/home/tomcat/dumps'
export CATALINA_OPTS='-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:ErrorFile=$DUMPSPATH/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=$DUMPSPATH'
/opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/bin/startup.sh
```

Just wanted to check if DUMPSPATH variable is used correctly in export statement or should DUMPSPATH be enclosed in curly brackets or parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the content of DUMPSPATH in CATALINA_OPTS (see [Variable Substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/varsubn.html)) you have to use doublequotes not single quote:

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -XX:ErrorFile=$DUMPSPATH/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=$DUMPSPATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as `$DUMPSPATH` is not followed by a character (such as `_`) that is a legal character for a parameter name, you are OK as-is. That said, it is never an error to use `${DUMPSPATH}`, so feel free to use it to be on the safe side.

Comment: thank you for your reply; I got it working now by using "" instead of '' in export line.

Comment: I didn't even look to see which quotes you were using :)